# Need help dealing with spacing issue in MaterialUI Dialog Content

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Im trying to have a summary page and using a MUI Dialog to acheive this.

This is the dialog I have:
[image: This]

But I am trying to make the two sides line up at the top instead of there being space above "Title 2". It seems that the Typographys are added from the bottom up starting with the last one in each div. The JSX Im using is:

```js
<Dialog className={classes.dialog} open={open} fullWidth maxWidth="md">
  <DialogTitle disableTypography className={classes.dialogTitle}>
    <Typography align="center" variant="h5">
      Summary
    </Typography>
  </DialogTitle>
  <DialogContent dividers>
    <div
      className={
        booleanVar === true ? classes.test1 : classes.test3
      }
    >
      <Typography
        align="center"
        variant="h6"
      >{`Title 1`}</Typography>
      <Typography align="left" variant="h6">{`Three`}</Typography>
      <Typography align="left" variant="h6">{`Line`}</Typography>
      <Typography align="left" variant="h6">{`Email:`}</Typography>
    </div>
    {booleanVar === true ? (
      <div className={classes.test2}>
        <Typography
          align="center"
          variant="h6"
        >{`Title 2`}</Typography>
        <Typography variant="h6">{`Two Line`}</Typography>
        <Typography variant="h6">{`Example`}</Typography>
      </div>
    ) : null}
  </DialogContent>
</Dialog>
```

Additionally, the CSS is:

```css
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  dialog: {
    borderRadius: "10px",
    height: "auto",
    justifyContent: "center",
    margin: "auto",
    width: "auto"
  },
  dialogTitle: {
    padding: "6px 24px 16px 24px",
    textAlign: "center"
  },
  test1: {
    width: "49%",
    margin: "auto",
    textAlign: "left",
    display: "inline-block",
    paddingRight: "5px"
  },
  test2: {
    width: "49%",
    margin: "auto",
    textAlign: "center",
    display: "inline-block",
    borderLeft: "0.1em solid #e0e0e0",
    paddingLeft: "5px"
  },
  test3: {
    width: "100%",
    margin: "auto",
    textAlign: "center",
    display: "inline-block"
  }
}));
```

If anyone knows a solution with the CSS thats what Id prefer but I am open to any working solution!

Comment: If you host this reproducible issue on codesandbox, it would be easier to resolve it

Comment: It's not letting me add material-ui/core as a dependency

Comment: Add your code here, I have created this one here: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-meadow-iv9z8

Make sure you save it after adding the code, and share the link back again

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding, I have the code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-chatterjee-8rgqh?file=/src/App.js Additionally resizing the window can make the second div go under the first one instead of next to it, so if you know a solution to that Id appreciate @PrathameshKoshti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find the origin of the issue, but I achieved the layout you wanted.

I modified the myDialog.js file a little bit, I removed the `margin: "auto"`, as it was not serving any purpose to your code from all three test classes namely `test1`, `test2` and `test3`.

After that imported a `Box` component from Material UI like this:

```js
import {
  Box, // here
  Button,
  Typography,
  Dialog,
  DialogActions,
  DialogTitle,
  DialogContent,
  IconButton
} from "@material-ui/core";
```

Then wrapped the dialog content with the `<Box>` component and added `display="flex"` property to make apply flexbox layout to the wrapped div this way:

```js
<Box display="flex">
   <div
     className={
       booleanVar !== undefined ? classes.test1 : classes.test3
     }
   >
     <Typography align="center" variant="h6">{`Title 1`}</Typography>
     <Typography align="left" variant="h6">{`Three`}</Typography>
     <Typography align="left" variant="h6">{`Line`}</Typography>
     <Typography align="left" variant="h6">{`Example`}</Typography>
   </div>
   {booleanVar !== undefined ? (
   <div className={classes.test2}>
     <Typography align="center" variant="h6">{`Title 2`}</Typography>
     <Typography align="left" variant="h6">{`Two Line`}</Typography>
     <Typography align="left" variant="h6">{`Example`}</Typography>
   </div>
   ) : null}
</Box>
```

You can check the codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/still-https-71skf